# How get file from a directory using relative path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am pretty new in C# and I am finding some difficulties trying to retrieve a jpg file that is into a directory of my project.

I have the following situation:

I have a **Solution** that is named **MySolution**, inside this solution there are some projects including a **project** named **PdfReport**. Inside this project there is a **folder** named **Shared** and inside this folder there is an **header.jpg** file.

Now if I want to obtain the list of all files that are inside the **Shared** directory (that as explained is a directory inside my project) I can do something like this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\Shared\");
```

and this work fine but I don't want use absolute path but I'd rather use a **relative path** relative to the **PdfReport** project.

I am searching a solution to do that but, untill now, I can't found it. Can you help me to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Provided your application's Executable Path is "C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2", you can access the PdfReport\Shared folder as

```
string exePath =  System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string sharedPath = Path.Combine(exePath, "PdfReport\\Shared\\");
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sharedPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the current folder by using this

```
Server.MapPath(".");
```

In a non ASP.NET application but WinForms or Console or WPF application you should use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: but this only if I am in a .NET web application or also in a standard application?

Comment: What do you mean by a standard application?

Comment: a non web application

Comment: `Environment` is the class that does that in local application

Comment: @AndreaNobili It might be prudent to remove the `asp.net` tag then; given that, the answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want root relative, you can do this (assuming C:\Develop\EarlyWarning is site root)

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/public/Implementazione/Ver2/PdfReport/Shared"));
```

Or if you want plain relative,

```
//assuming you're in the public folder
string[] filePathes = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Implementazione/Ver2/PdfReport/Shared"));
```

Root relative is usually best in my experience, in case you move the code around.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on your file **header.jpg**, choose Properties, and select for example the option **Copy always** on the property "Copy to Output Directory".

Then a method like this, in any class that belongs to project PdfReport:

```
public string[] ReadFiles()
{
    return Directory.GetFiles("Shared");
}
```

will work well.

Alternatively, if you have files that never change at runtime and you want to have access to them inside the assembly you also can embed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292/en-us